# Use IF into datatable with primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I have a if into a Datatable, but doest show any results. For test if this its works, i put in the code *test="#{listaTrabajo.estado eq 1}"`* and it shows all the records. I need show records just when "estado" equals 1.

```
<p:dataTable id="tablaDeListas" var="listaTrabajo" value="#{crearEstrategiaBeans.listaListasDeTrabajo}" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <c:if test="#{listaTrabajo.estado eq 1}">
        <p:column style="width:2%;" headerText="#"  >
            <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex+1}" />
        </p:column>      
        <p:column style="width:7%;" headerText="ID LT">
            <h:outputText value="#{listaTrabajo.id}" />
        </p:column>      
        <p:column style="width:20%;" headerText="Nombre Lista">
            <h:outputText   value="#{listaTrabajo.nombreLista}" />                                      
        </p:column>                             
    </c:if>    
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: So it works if you use an `h:datatable`? That is what your title sort of suggests... it won't work there either...

Comment: Its duplicated. Thanks.